# Repeat JS Textillate function each time modal is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

I am using uikit modal on a project. I am also using JS Textillate to animate the text when the modal is opened. However, I want the text to be animated if the modal is closed and opened again continuously. For now, it only animate once when the modal is opened for the first time, when closed and opened again, the animation does not run again.
This is the JavaScript code below:

```
$(".uk-modal-full").on('show', function(){
  var $title = $(".txt").textillate({
    // in animation settings.
    in: {
      effect: "fadeIn", // set the effect name
    },
    // out animation settings.
    out: {
      effect: "fadeOut",
      delayScale: 0,
      delay: 0,
    },
    type: "char",
    autoStart: true,
  }); 

  var $title = $(".txt2").textillate({
    // in animation settings.
    in: {
      effect: "fadeIn", // set the effect name
    },
    // out animation settings.
    out: {
      effect: "fadeOut",
      delayScale: 0,
      delay: 0,
    },
    type: "char",
    autoStart: true,
  });  
});
```

I am thinking maybe the function can be removed when modal closes so that it can be repeated when it is opened again. I am not sure if that is possible as I am only a Jquery learner.

```
$(".uk-modal-full").on('hide', function(){
  // code here?
});
```

Full options for Textillate is here https://github.com/jschr/textillate

**UPDATE**

Thank you! I have created a codepen here to test my full code inside a modal using your example. It seems to be working but with some issues. When I use `$element.textillate('in')` and `$element.textillate('out')`, the other options do not work (e.g. initialDelay). It seems to only control the `"in"` and `"out"` options. When I used `$element.textillate('start')` and `$element.textillate('stop')`, the other options worked but when modal is reopened, the text are briefly loaded first before animating.

Please see codepen here - https://codepen.io/ajaxthemestudios/pen/XWJRBbW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the readme of `Textillate`, I think this section is what you need:

> $element.textillate('start') - Manually start/restart textillate
>
> $element.textillate('stop') - Manually pause/stop textillate
>
> $element.textillate('in') - Trigger the current text's in animation
>
> $element.textillate('out') - Trigger the current text's out animation

So I would do something like first define the animations (outside the event functions)

```js
var title1 = $(".txt").textillate({
    // in animation settings.
    in: {
      effect: "fadeIn", // set the effect name
    },
    // out animation settings.
    out: {
      effect: "fadeOut",
      delayScale: 0,
      delay: 0,
    },
    type: "char",
    autoStart: false,
  });

var title2 = $(".txt").textillate({
    // in animation settings.
    in: {
      effect: "fadeIn", // set the effect name
    },
    // out animation settings.
    out: {
      effect: "fadeOut",
      delayScale: 0,
      delay: 0,
    },
    type: "char",
    autoStart: false,
  });
```

And then in the event function:

```js
$(".uk-modal-full").on('show', function(){
   title1.textillate('in');
   title2.textillate('in');
}
```

**EDIT**

I got it to work in this codepen: https://codepen.io/thomas-short/pen/zYxdzWY

Test it by clicking on `click` repeatedly.

**EDIT 2**

The problem of the text being briefly visible seems to be a limitation of the library. I could not find a way to solve it using the tools they provide. The only way I managed to make it work is by control it myself:

```js
$(".uk-modal-full").on('show', function(){
    title1.textillate('start');

    $(".txt2").hide();
  
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(".txt2").show();

      title2.textillate('start');
    }, 1500);
})
```

And remove `initialDelay` from the options

Comment: Thank you! I just posted an update above after following your suggestion. There are some issues

Comment: @atsngr See my edit to my post for a solution to your issue (under **EDIT 2**)

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a good workaround. I had to use `$element.textillate('in')` and `$element.textillate('out')` to stop the initial flick when modal is reopened. The only other issues is to get rid of the jump in position of the first text due to the second text being initially hidden

Comment: You can just dinfine a minium height with `min-height` and that should prevent the flicker. If this answer helped you, please consider giving it the green tick. Thanks 

Comment: I eventually used `$(".txt2").css('opacity', '0');` and `$(".txt2").css('opacity', '1');` instead of `$(".txt2").hide()` and `$(".txt2").hide()` and it sorted out the issue. Thanks for the help